# How can I call with native Swift methods from Electron app using javascript?

Tags: in-app-purchase, electron, in-app-billing, hybrid-mobile-app, mac-app-store

I am looking to add in-app subscriptions to the mac desktop app so I can submit to app store.

I have the code written for iOS using the cordova plugin: https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

But for electron there exists no such plugin.

So I can use the native swift code from the plugin, but need a way to write a custom plugin so I can call swift methods from javascript running the Electron app.

Please let me know how to approach this, or point me to the correct resources.

Thanks You

Comment: afaik there isn't stable binding for swift to node, doubt if it's possible to interop it.

Comment: hmm there has to be some solution!

Comment: if you able to find stable binding or write bindings for yourself, maybe.